# Авторизация через Google на сайте для избранных доменов (почт)

Tags: wordpress, oauth, google-oauth2

Интересует вопрос, возможно ли в настройка приложения Google OAuth сделать так чтобы на сайт можно было войти только с определенных доменов (почт)?

Возможно есть функционал на стороне Google OAuth чтобы запретить вход и регистрацию на сайте для все (White List для авторизации)
Сайт работает на WordPress

**Буду рад любому совету и помощи, спасибо!**

Comment: Добавте фильтр User Email перед отправкой на сервер запроса... распарсив email адрксс. Это вроде не сложно, или оплатите и вам сделают.

Comment: UPD:
Пример:
Сайт на WordPress с авторизацией через Google, надо сделать возможность пропускать только те домены (почты) которые добавлены в список разрешенных для авторизации например - mail@example.com а другие отклонять - mail@gmail.com